# Getting a token with msal.net library is not giving me the right audience in the claims of the token

Tags: azure, office365, azure-ad-msal

I'm using MSAL.net library to get a token with AcquireTokenInteractive but I'm getting this audience in the claims "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000", I'm expecting to get the client id of my azure app in the audience fields,

```
List<string> scopesList = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email", "User.Read" };

result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
```

**Update**: I realized that I'm getting the client id in the appid claim but I need it in the audience

Comment: Your scope list variable is named scopesList, but you pass scopes' in calling the Acquire Token interactive method. Also, when you registered your App, have you enabled for ID tokens? Refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc)

Comment: yeah, well that's just an example, I'm pretty sure I'm passing the scopes

Comment: what platform have you registered your app in AD - web or desktop? Did you check for ID tokens enabled for that app registration.